# Search and export to excel with php

Tags: php, excel

i have to write module search and export to excel with php.But if data is big,it is very slow.I think i will create a button download excel after user has search,i don't know how do it?Please help me,thank you very much!!

Comment: Please give some code samples. It's rather hard for me to help you right now, not knowing what information is displayed to the user, how it's displayed and how the system works in the first place (and why it is slow in the first place). Also, does it need to be a specific excel format, or will CSV be good enough?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough details for me to help you with search, but here's an easy way to export to a CSV file (which Excel can open):

```
$f = fopen('export.csv', 'w');
foreach ($data as $row) fputcsv($f, $row);
fclose($f);
```

This is assuming that $data is an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow following steps:

- [Search something using forms on webpage.](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/forms.php)
- Create SQL query using user entered search terms.
- Fetch result from database.
- Store this **result** in array.
- Show this result on webpage by looping using **result** array.
- Now there is a button on same webpage to export result into CSV/Excel
- [This button submit functionality will use same **result** array to export CSV](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

If you are allowed to use Javascript/jQuery:

- [Announcements: TableTools v1.0.2 - Save as Excel, CSV, copy and print](http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=327)
- [HTML Table to CSV](http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php)

Comment: This will require the script to run again in order to compile the csv file, and since user547442 stated that the script was slow, this might not be such a great solution. Obviously the script probably could be optimized, but otherwise, it might be smarter to send the user the raw data and then have JS/ jQuery take care of displaying it/ building the csv file.

Comment: @Battle_707: We don't know that what OP is implemented so far. OP is also said that his solution is slow. So I guess that he is fetching search result from database to display and fetching result again from database to export csv. So I asked him to use same result array for both. OP did not tag his question with jquery/js. So we have to provide solution in PHP. I asked him about using jQuery in first comment on his question. He did't reply so far..